# How to compute the eigenvalues?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, inverse, matrix-calculus

Suppose $W=(X'X + kI)^{-1}$ and $Z=(I + k(X'X)^{-1})^{-1}$, $k>0$, and suppose also that $\lambda_i$ are eigenvalues of $X'X$. How to get the following conclusions about their eigenvalues.

1. The eigenvalues of $W$ is $1 / (\lambda_i + k)$;
2. The eigenvalues of $Z$ is $\lambda_i / (\lambda_i + k)$.

They are claimed from [the original ridge regression paper](http://amstat.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00401706.1970.10488634).

The question might be trivial to you but I just had trouble working with inversion.

Answer (score 0):

The basic point is that if $f$ is any rational function and $A$ is a matrix such that $f(A)$ is defined (i.e. none of the eigenvalues of $A$ is a pole of $f$), then $f$ maps the spectrum of $A$ to the spectrum of $f(A)$.  Thus for (2.), we take $f(z) = 1/(1+k/z) = z/(z+k)$, and get the desired conclusion if $\lambda_i$ are the eigenvalues of $A = X'X$ and none of the $\lambda_i$ are $-k$ (which is the case if $k > 0$,  $X$ is real, and $'$ denotes transpose).

Comment: Thanks. That makes great sense. Is there any formal/general theorem related to your answer? I'd like to read through if any.